# Sprite Rendering Cost Calculation

Tags: unity, textures, sprites, rendering, texture-atlas

First of all asking before asking this question I have already read following post for the clearance of my mind.

[Sprite Renderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-SpriteRenderer.html)

[Texture 2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Texture2D.html)

I want to change my background texture as per device aspect ratio detection. For this purpose I have following code:

```
var newSprite : Sprite; 

function Start () {
      GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = newSprite;
}
```

Or another way to load sprite is :

```
Sprite myFruit = Resources.Load("fruits_1", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

Using above code I can able to load new sprite as per my requirement. But I want to reduce following disadvantage from this.

At present basically I set background sprite of 960 x 640 for iPhone 4 and its get loaded. After that I change my background sprite to 2048 x 1536 as I detect the device with iPad Retina display. So another texture get loaded. I want this process to happen single time so how to manage sprite texture in correct way.

Also thanks for your attention towards this question.

Comment: Don't set the background sprite immediately...

Comment: Please clarify more on this.